# Fan works more in Ubuntu for same temperature than Windows

Tags: fan, temperature

In Windows, with 52 degree temperature fan works normal.
but in Ubuntu with same temperature it works more than windows,even during viewing HQ jpg pics and web browsing. This happens only in AC mode.

In battery mode, fan speed is OK.

I tested using `tlp` and grub acpi_osi=windows 2012 methods but no result.

- Machine: hp 8460p
- GPU: amd 7400m gpu.
- CPU: core i5
- Ubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: Sorry for the necrobumping, but did you solve this problem by any chance? I have now the very same laptop, HP 8460p, and fans are driving me nuts :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems your laptop BIOS has a Fan Always on while on AC power setting. You could try disabling it to see it improves your situation.

1. Power on or restart the computer, and then press esc when the "Press the ESC key for Startup Menu" message displays at the bottom of the screen.
2. Press F10 to enter Computer Setup.
3. Select System Configuration from the top menu. Select Device
   Configurations.
4. Deselect "Fan Always on while AC Power".

Source: http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c03944281